# Why can't I save the Virtualbox 2D acceleration settings

Tags: 18.04, virtualbox, windows-10, 2d

I am running Ubuntu 18.04.03 as host and have a Windowss 10 guest(both 64 bit). Virtualbox version 6. I have guest additions installed and 3D acceleration works, but when I got to display and check the box for 2D acceleration and click okay, it doesn't save it.

As soon as I go back, it is unchecked again. Not sure what this bug is and would appreciate any help. I have been trying to fix this for quite a while.

Currently my best guess is that either...

1. ... my virtualbox edition has an issue, or
2. ... 2D acceleration isn't supported.
   But if it isn't supported, I would have expected the CheckBox to be greyed out...